# Getting a segmentation fault in simple NASM operation; moving matrix pointer into ecx register

Tags: arrays, assembly, nasm

I'm working on a program that will be able to find the maximum element in an array. For some reason, I am getting a segmentation fault when I try to move the first element on the matrix into the ecx register for output (just testing it).

I've tried all different kinds of addressing modes to be sure, but I can't figure out why I am getting this fault and nothing is working.

Here's my code:

```
segment .data

    NUM_ROWS: equ 5
    NUM_COLUMNS: equ 5
    NUM_ROW_BYTES: equ 10

    ;Default matrix
    matrix: dd  5, 4, 9, 7, 2, 1, 4, 6, 8, 7
            ;9, 9, 2, 3, 7
            ;6, 5, 8, 3, 4
            ;1, 2, 8, 2, 6  
    matrixLen: equ $-matrix

    sum:    db "The sum of the last column is: ", 10

    ;FOR TESTING
    works: db 'Works!', 10
    worksLen: equ $-works

segment .bss
    counter resb 1

segment .text
    global main

main:
    mov eax, 4      ; system call 4
    mov ebx, 1      ; standard output 
    mov ecx, [matrix + 4]   
    mov edx, 4
    int 0x80
```

Comment: your passing a value to sys_write. it expects an address of a string/char.  even if you do `mov ecx, matrix` then `add ecx, 4` it still won't work.  you could either define matrix as an array of bytes intead of dwords or convert the value to ascii

Comment: So there's no way to output a value on its own? How do I convert it to ASCII?

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking through [this list of Linux syscalls](http://asm.sourceforge.net/syscall.html) I found and there doesn't seem to be any calls that just print one char. You're stuck using sys_write(), though it can print one char if you set EDX to 1 and pass it a valid pointer.

Recognize that `mov ecx, [matrix + 4]` only moves the value of pointed to by (matrix+4) into ECX so that sys_write will use that as the address. Since that address contains 4, sys_write tried to print the string data it found starting at address 0x00000004. That's why it segfaulted (not allowed to read from there).

To convert the value 4 to an ASCII value suitable for printing, add 0x30 to the value. ASCII 0x30 = '0', 0x31 = '1' ... **0x34 = '4'** ... 0x39 = '9'.

Thus, a strategy for printing a *single* digit is to load that digit into ECX, add 0x30, shove into into a byte that you reserved in your `.bss` segment (maybe `digit_to_ascii resb 1`) and then move the address of `digit_to_ascii` into ECX before calling sys_write (and only set EDX to 1, since you only want to print 1 byte).

Understand that this only works for printing 1 digit. If you want to print a number 10 or higher, you need to break out each digit by division and print it individually (or write it individually into a reserved buffer and print the entire buffer using one sys_write call).

Comment: The overhead of single character writes is pretty high, so people try not to do it.  You are much better off getting used to building buffers of texts (e.g., for all your digits) and outputting the entire buffer rather than one character at a time.  This is why there isn't a "print_one_character" call.